# Can not scrape table after opening new web page tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am using the selenium package to go from one webpage to generate a table in another. Afterwards, I want to scrape from that generated table with beautifulsoup.

```
#Open Webpage
url = "https://www.website.com"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\mypathto\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

#Click Necessary Parameters
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Output').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="flexOpt"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[3]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="flexOpt"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[4]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="repOpt"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[4]').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Dates').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="RangeOption"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Range"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/select/option[2]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Range"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/select/option[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Range"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/select/option[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Range"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/select/option[2]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Range"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/select/option[31]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Range"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/select/option[1]').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Groupings').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availFld_DATE"]/a/img').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availFld_LOCID"]/a/img').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availFld_STATE"]/a/img').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availFld_DDSO_SA"]/a/img').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availFld_CLASS_ID"]/a/img').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="availFld_REGION"]/a/img').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Run').click()
time.sleep(2)

#scrape new web page
df_url = driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
df_url = driver.current_url
page = requests.get(df_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features = 'html5lib')
print(soup.prettify())
```

However, the only html I am getting is the following...

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Is there a reason for that? When I open up the new tab, I see  and  to use for scraping. How can I be able to have python read the part of the html I'm looking for?

Comment: is the table generated using javascript? if so, you would not be able to scrape that using requests and BS.

Comment: too many clicks, you should put some more sleep time in between clicks

Comment: Why combine Selenium, requests and BeautifulSoup like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using requests, try to save the page_source as text for beautiful soup to parse.

```
#scrape new web page
df_url = driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
df_url = driver.current_url
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
```